# Importar CSV a SQL Server 2012 Con campos descriptivos con comas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un archivo .csv que necesito importar a sql server 2012.
Ya he creado la tabla
Luego realice el insert.
El problema que tengo es que en la tabla hay campos descriptivos que tienen comas dentro de si mismos, por ejemplo en la columna domicilio muchos registros tienen cosas como

```
Aguero 3400, CABA
```

Con lo cual se dificulta la division de campos.
Quisiera saber como hacer para poder filtrar esos campos como una columna sola, si es que existe una manera no manual de borrar las comas dentro de ellos.

```
BULK
INSERT tabla
FROM 'C:\datos.CSV'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW=2, 
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
KEEPNULLS
);
GO
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se genera el CSV?

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente tanto `BULK INSERT` como el `bcp` si encuentran un `FIELDTERMINATOR` aún si estuviera en un texto "entrecomillado" por ejemplo `"Av Lope de vega, al 1300", "CABA"` lo va a terminar interpretando como un separador.

> If a terminator character occurs within the data, it is interpreted as
>   a terminator, not as data, and the data after that character is
>   interpreted as belonging to the next field or record. Therefore,
>   choose your terminators carefully to make sure that they never appear
>   in your data.

fuente: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485(v=sql.100).aspx

La alternativa óptima sería, siempre que tengas control con el proceso de exportación a CSV, usar otro separador menos común, por ejemplo el pipe `|` o reemplazar al generar las comas dentro del cada campo.

Si no controlas el proceso de exportación estas en un problema, podrías eventualmente importar las líneas completas en un solo campo y aplicar luego alguna lógica cuasi mágica a cada fila (verificando cantidad de comas) para poder detectar la coma válida de la inválida. Por ejemplo, si el siguiente campo de la dirección tiene que ser una lista determinada, por ejemplo, si fuera, digamos Tipo de documento (ej, DNI, CEDULA, etc) podrías asumir que en realidad el campo no finaliza con la coma de  `"Av Lope de vega, al 1300"` sino con la que esta justo antes de `DNI` o `CEDULA`, o eventualmente si el siguiente campo es un numérico, podrías verifica por `ISNUMERIC()`.

Answer (score 0):

Abre el archivo CSV en un editor (Excel por ejemplo). Después vuelves a guardar el archivo CSV pero indicando que el delimitador es un ';'(punto y coma) u otro.

Si lo prefieres puedes editar el archivo CSV manualmente (con el bloc de notas) cambiando a mano las comas por otro delimitador.

Cuando vuelvas a importar indicas cual es el 'nuevo' delimitador.